# Where is erase_if?

Tags: c++, stl

I've got a container and would like to erase elements based on a predicate. `erase_if` sounds familiar, but I can't find it in C++. What's the name and where is it defined?
I'd like to use it with a lambda in VS10.

Answer (score 35):

You're probably looking for [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), in a pattern such as:

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), predicate), vec.end());
```

Comment: And you'll find it in `<algorithm>`, along with the other standard algorithms.

Comment: erases single item

Comment: erase_if is a C++ 20 library and is in algorithm

Answer (score 14):

It's in [Library Fundamentals v2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/lib_extensions_2#Uniform_container_erasure), and soon in [C++20](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1209r0.html).

Comment: It looks like GCC supports this (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20) but I cannot figure out how to enable it with GCC not supporting c++20 in full yet. Do you know what flags to add to include this library?

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose make sure to pass appropriate `-std=` switch: https://godbolt.org/z/o7c63Mvd4

Answer (score 6):

MSVC does not yet implement C++20's `std::erase_if` from [P1209R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1209r0.html) so, as a workaround, you can just copy the implementation for specific container from that paper somewhere to your code. GCC 9.1 and Clang 9.0 already have it.

```
namespace std {

// for std::string
template <class charT, class traits, class A, class Predicate>
void erase_if(basic_string<charT, traits, A>& c, Predicate pred) {
    c.erase(remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), pred), c.end());
}

// for std::deque
template <class T, class A, class Predicate>
void erase_if(deque<T, A>& c, Predicate pred) {
    c.erase(remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), pred), c.end());
}

// for std::vector
template <class T, class A, class Predicate>
void erase_if(vector<T, A>& c, Predicate pred) {
    c.erase(remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), pred), c.end());
}

// for std::list
template <class T, class A, class Predicate>
void erase_if(list<T, A>& c, Predicate pred) {
    c.remove_if(pred);
}

// for std::forward_list
template <class T, class A, class Predicate>
void erase_if(forward_list<T, A>& c, Predicate pred) {
    c.remove_if(pred);
}

// for std::map
template <class K, class T, class C, class A, class Predicate>
void erase_if(map<K, T, C, A>& c, Predicate pred) {
    for (auto i = c.begin(), last = c.end(); i != last; )
        if (pred(*i))
            i = c.erase(i);
        else
            ++i;
}

// for std::multimap
template <class K, class T, class C, class A, class Predicate>
void erase_if(multimap<K, T, C, A>& c, Predicate pred) {
    for (auto i = c.begin(), last = c.end(); i != last; )
        if (pred(*i))
            i = c.erase(i);
        else
            ++i;
}

// for std::set
template <class K, class C, class A, class Predicate>
void erase_if(set<K, C, A>& c, Predicate pred) {
    for (auto i = c.begin(), last = c.end(); i != last; )
        if (pred(*i))
            i = c.erase(i);
        else
            ++i;
}

// for std::multiset
template <class K, class C, class A, class Predicate>
void erase_if(multiset<K, C, A>& c, Predicate pred) {
    for (auto i = c.begin(), last = c.end(); i != last; )
        if (pred(*i))
            i = c.erase(i);
        else
            ++i;
}

// for std::unordered_map
template <class K, class T, class H, class P, class A, class Predicate>
void erase_if(unordered_map<K, T, H, P, A>& c, Predicate pred) {
    for (auto i = c.begin(), last = c.end(); i != last; )
        if (pred(*i))
            i = c.erase(i);
        else
            ++i;
}

// for std::unordered_multimap
template <class K, class T, class H, class P, class A, class Predicate>
void erase_if(unordered_multimap<K, T, H, P, A>& c, Predicate pred) {
    for (auto i = c.begin(), last = c.end(); i != last; )
        if (pred(*i))
            i = c.erase(i);
        else
            ++i;
}

// for std::unordered_set
template <class K, class H, class P, class A, class Predicate>
void erase_if(unordered_set<K, H, P, A>& c, Predicate pred) {
    for (auto i = c.begin(), last = c.end(); i != last; )
        if (pred(*i))
            i = c.erase(i);
        else
            ++i;
}

// for std::unordered_multiset
template <class K, class H, class P, class A, class Predicate>
void erase_if(unordered_multiset<K, H, P, A>& c, Predicate pred) {
    for (auto i = c.begin(), last = c.end(); i != last; )
        if (pred(*i))
            i = c.erase(i);
        else
            ++i;
}

} // namespace std
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you're thinking of [`remove_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/) which takes a predicate to determine if the element ought to be removed.

`remove_if` returns an iterator pointing to the beginning of the elements to remove in the container.  To actually remove them you need to use `erase`:

```
container.erase(remove_if(container.start(), container.end(), pred), container.end())
```

---

Either that or perhaps you mistakenly recalled the `copy_if` algorithm?  Which somehow got left out of the standard but was written about - and implemented - in [Effective STL](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html).

Comment: erases single item

Answer (score 2):

Actually there exists a method called `erase_if` in the Boost library for [pointer containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_sequence_adapter.html).

Answer (score 2):

With the new C++ 20 format you can use it like this:

```
vector<int> vec {1,2,3,4,5};
auto no_of_removed_elements = std::erase_if(vec,[](const int a){return a==5;});
```

[Link to the reference.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `list::remove_if`, but not for all container classes. `remove_if` also exists as a algorithm, which can be used with the iterators you can get from `begin()` and `end()`.