# Erase elements in a vector of struct according to a property value

Tags: c++, stl, vector, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is erase_if?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424962/where-is-erase-if)

I have structure as follows:

```
struct V {
 int x;
 int y;
}:
```

and I have an stl vector of struct elements

```
vector<struct V> v1;
```

I would like to erase from the vector all elements having the attribute y less than a certain value.

How could I please do that using `std::remove_if` by defining a predicate associated to the structure.

That is the predicate that I defined but that does not seem to be correct.

```
struct less_than_value
{
 const int value;

 bool operator()(const struct V p) const
 {
    return p.y < value;
 }
};
```

Comment: `std::erase_if`?  There is no such function in the C++ standard.

Comment: [Do you mean `std::remove_if`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424962/where-is-erase-if)

Comment: I thought that `std::remove_if` was for lists only.

Comment: I corrected my question. Sorry it is `remove_if`

Comment: @rpsml: `std::list::remove_if` is for lists only.  `std::remove_if` is global.  They do different things too.  The list version, since it knows about its container, is able to actually resize the container.  `std::remove_if` just moves elements to the front of the range delineated by the iterators passed to it.

Comment: Regardless, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3425075/8747, answers his question. `vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), predicate), vec.end());`

Comment: @rpsml: There is an `std::remove_if` algorithm (in `<algorithm>`) that applies (as most other algorithms) to iterators. There is also a `std::list<>::remove_if` member function in the list class with slightly different semantics (`std::remove_if` does not modify the container, `std::list<>::remove_if` will *erase* elements from the container)

Comment: @Benjamin and David, thanks for the information. This will shorten some of my code that iterates through all elements and checks for deletes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) with a suitable predicate:

```
bool my_predicate(const V& item)
{
   // apply some logic and return true or false
   return item.x == 42;
}

#include <algorithm>

std::vector<V> v1 = ....;
v1.erase( remove_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), my_predicate), v1.end() );
```

In the example above, all elements with data member `x` equal to 42 will be removed.

**Edit**:  looking at your example, you would need to do something like

```
less_than_value pred = {5};
v1.erase( remove_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), pred), v1.end() );
```

Comment: @tuxworker I added an example.

Comment: @tuxworker It would have made a better question had you mentioned that in the question along with an explanation of what you've tried.

Comment: @ShawnChin I added what I've tried

Comment: @juanchopanza Thank you for your answer. It works for me. Indeed, my predicate was correct but I did not use erase :(

Answer (score 5):

In C++11 that is simple enough with a lambda:

```
v1.erase( std::remove_if( v1.begin(), v1.end(), [](V const& v) { return v.y<value; }),
          v1.end());
```

In C++03 it is a bit more convoluted and can be done in one of multiple ways: create functor with the same behavior as the lambda above; use *bindery magic* (consider `boost::bind` for a slightly simpler approach). Using the bindery magic here is going to be quite convoluted so I would avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be wanting to use remove_if (there is no erase_if: how would you implement an erasure that is unaware of the container its being removed from?)

Here's a (compiled, tested) program that demonstrates how one might do that:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct V
{
    int x; 
    int y;
};

bool y_less_than_5(V const &v)
{
    return v.y < 5;
}


int main()
{
    vector<V> vec;
    V v;
    v.x = 4;  v.y = 1; vec.push_back(v);
    v.x = 17; v.y = 3; vec.push_back(v);
    v.x = 21; v.y = 5; vec.push_back(v);
    v.x = 36; v.y = 7; vec.push_back(v);
    v.x = 25; v.y = 9; vec.push_back(v);

    vec.erase(
        remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), y_less_than_5),
        vec.end());

    for(vector<V>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << "[" << it->x << "," << it->y << "]" << endl;
    }
}
```

output:

```
[21,5]
[36,7]
[25,9]
```

Your exact method of providing a predicate may differ, but that's a different question ;)